# Не работает текстовый ref React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class F extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        name: 'User'
      };
  }

  Input(){
    this.setState({name: this.refs.Txt.value})
  }   

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Привет {this.state.name}!</div>
        <input ref = "Txt" onChange={this.Input}></input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <F/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите получить `value` input'a при определенном событии, то ref'ы Вам не нужны:

```
return (
  <div>
    <input 
      onChange={event => this.setState({ name: event.target.value })}      
      value={this.state.name} 
    />
  </div>
)
```

Но если они все же необходимы, то для их создания стоит использовать [createRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) (классы) или [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) (хуки):

```
// классы
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.myRef = React.createRef()
}
console.log(this.myRef.current)
render (
  return <div ref={this.myRef} />
)

// хуки
const myRef = React.useRef()
console.log(myRef.current)
return <div ref={myRef} />
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Но мне оочень интересно в чем конкретно проблема с ref`ом, нужно прежде всего для саморазвития, ибо в гугле не нашел ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: @LiloRandl дополнил ответ